# Drawing outside the canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawing

I am a beginner.
I'm working on a drawing wpf project. I draw lines in a canvas control. I want to control zooming and panning. I save the lines in a list with the actual coordinates which I transform to display them.
It almost works.
On the other hand I don't understand why some lines are drawn outside the canvas?

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace WPFcanvasZoomMove
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        const double _tX = 1;
        const double _tY = -1;

        double _originX;
        double _originY;

        double _zoom;

        List<Element> _elements;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode=

            _zoom = 1;


            CanvasModel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            
            CanvasModel.MouseMove += CanvasModel_MouseMove;
            CanvasModel.MouseWheel += CanvasModel_MouseWheel;


            _elements = new List<Element>();
            Element e;

            e = new Element(new Point(-500, 0), new Point(500, 0), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue), 2);
            _elements.Add(e);
            e = new Element(new Point(0, -500), new Point(0, 500), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue), 2);
            _elements.Add(e);
            e = new Element(new Point(50, 70), new Point(100, 30), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 4);
            _elements.Add(e);

            //e = new Element(new Point(125, 60), new Point(175, -70), new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green), 10);
            //_elements.Add(e);

        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {

            CanvasModel.BringIntoView();
            Redraw();

        }

        private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //_originX = CanvasModel.ActualWidth / 2;
            //_originY = CanvasModel.ActualHeight / 2;

            _originX = 75;
            _originY = 130;

            lblMouseZoomFactor.Content = $"fZ={_zoom.ToString()}";

            lblMouseDeltaX.Content = $"dX={_originX.ToString()}";
            lblMouseDeltaY.Content = $"dY={_originY.ToString()}";

            Redraw();

        }

        public void Redraw()
        {
            DrawLine();
        }

        public void DrawLine()
        {

            CanvasModel.Children.Clear();
            // Dessiner
            foreach (Element e in _elements)
            {
                //CanvasModel.Children.Add(e.ToWorld(_dX,_dY,_zoom));
                //CanvasModel.Children.Add(e.ToWorld(_originX, _originY, _zoom));
                //CanvasModel.Children.Add(e.ToModel());
                CanvasModel.Children.Add(e.ToWorld(_originX, _originY, _zoom));
                                
            }

        }

        private void CanvasModel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            //Matrice de transformation
            Matrix m;

            //Position de la souris dans le canvas (coordonnées wpf)
            Point ptCanvas = e.GetPosition(this.CanvasModel);
            lblMouseCanvasPositionX.Content = $"Xc={ptCanvas.X.ToString()}";
            lblMouseCanvasPositionY.Content = $"Yc={ptCanvas.Y.ToString()}";

            //Position de la souris dans le Model
            //Translation par rapport à l'origine
            m = new Matrix();
            m.Translate(-_originX, -_originY);
            Point ptModel = m.Transform(ptCanvas);
            ptModel=new Point(ptModel.X, -ptModel.Y);
            lblMouseModelPositionX.Content = $"Xm={ptModel.X.ToString()}";
            lblMouseModelPositionY.Content = $"Ym={ptModel.Y.ToString()}";

            //Position de la souris dans le World
            //Echelle par rapport au zoom
            m = new Matrix();
            m.ScaleAt(_zoom, _zoom, 0, 0);
            Point ptW = m.Transform(ptModel);
            lblMouseWorldPositionX.Content = $"Xw={ptW.X.ToString()}";
            lblMouseWorldPositionY.Content = $"Yw={ptW.Y.ToString()}";

            Redraw();

        }

        private void CanvasModel_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {

            //Debug.WriteLine($"e.delta={e.Delta}");

            double kz = 1200;
            _zoom += e.Delta / kz;

            lblMouseZoomFactor.Content = $"fZ={_zoom.ToString()}";

            Redraw();
        }

    }

    public class Element
    {

        private Point _PointWorldStart;
        public Point PointWorldStart
        {
            get { return _PointWorldStart; }
            set { _PointWorldStart = value; }
        }


        private Point _PointWorldEnd;
        public Point PointWorldEnd
        {
            get { return _PointWorldEnd; }
            set { _PointWorldEnd = value; }
        }

        private Point _PointModelStart;
        public Point PointModelStart
        {
            get { return _PointModelStart; }
            set { _PointModelStart = value; }
        }


        private Point _PointModelEnd;
        public Point PointModelEnd
        {
            get { return _PointModelEnd; }
            set { _PointModelEnd = value; }
        }

        private SolidColorBrush _Brush;
        public SolidColorBrush Brush
        {
            get { return _Brush; }
            set { _Brush = value; }
        }

        private int _Thickness;
        public int Thickness
        {
            get { return _Thickness; }
            set { _Thickness = value; }
        }

        public Element()
        {
            _PointWorldStart = new Point(0,0);
            _PointWorldEnd = new Point(0, 0);
            //_SolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255));
            _Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            _Thickness = 1;
        }

        public Element(Point PointStart, Point PointEnd, SolidColorBrush Brush, int Thickness)
        {
            _PointWorldStart = PointStart;
            _PointWorldEnd = PointEnd;
            _Brush = Brush;
            _Thickness = Thickness;
        }

        public Line ToModel()
        {
            Line l = new Line();
            l.X1 = _PointWorldStart.X;
            l.Y1 = _PointWorldStart.Y;
            l.X2 = _PointWorldEnd.X;
            l.Y2 = _PointWorldEnd.Y;
            l.StrokeThickness = _Thickness;
            l.Stroke = _Brush;
            return l;
        }

        public Line ToWorld(double deltaX, double deltaY, double zoomFactor)
        {
            Line l = new Line();
            l.X1 = ConvertPoint.ToWorld(_PointWorldStart, deltaX, deltaY, zoomFactor).X;
            l.Y1 = ConvertPoint.ToWorld(_PointWorldStart, deltaX, deltaY, zoomFactor).Y;
            l.X2 = ConvertPoint.ToWorld(_PointWorldEnd, deltaX, deltaY, zoomFactor).X;
            l.Y2 = ConvertPoint.ToWorld(_PointWorldEnd, deltaX, deltaY, zoomFactor).Y;
            l.StrokeThickness = _Thickness;
            l.Stroke = _Brush;
            return l;
        }

    }

    static class ConvertPoint
    {

        public static Point ToWorld(Point Point, double deltaX, double deltaY, double zoomFactor)
        {
            Matrix m;
            Point p = new Point(Point.X,-Point.Y);

            m = new Matrix();
            m.Translate(deltaX,deltaY);
            p = m.Transform(p);

            m = new Matrix();
            m.ScaleAt(zoomFactor, zoomFactor, 0, 0);
            p = m.Transform(p);

            Debug.WriteLine($"p={p.ToString()}");

            return p;
        }


    }

}
```

I would like the drawing to stay in the canvas.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question.
Are you expecting lines outside of the Canvas to not be rendered?
Or do you think that according to your data all the lines are within the Canvas?

Comment: My recommendation (not entirely related to the question): Do not be lazy for each type (class, structure) to create a new file. Reading code of several types in one file is terribly inconvenient. The search for such types in the project structure is also extremely inconvenient.

Comment: If you just want to hide a part of a line which goes beyond the Canvas, set `ClipToBounds="True"`.

Comment: Either clip the drawing or ensure that the coordinates you produces are within the bounds. To do this you can create a `Rect` with the dimensions of the Canvas. Then use `Rect.Contains(Point)` to test if the Point is outside the Canvas.

Comment: If you're scaling then the simplest approach I know of to clip: Nest your canvas inside another and clip the parent canvas.  You'll likely find clipping just the one canvas has complications.

Comment: The ClipToBounds="True" property is exactly what I want to get. Thanks.

Comment: Comment mettre le sujet en résolu ?